# Send commands to remote server using powershell

Tags: powershell

i'm new at powershell scripts

i want to uninstall softwares located in remote computer from my local computer
so i'm using

```
$computer =Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your server name or IP adress'
$user =Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your server username'
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {  

Write-host -ForegroundColor Magenta "Please select the software you wish to uninstall..."


    $javaVer = Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*", "HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" | select DisplayName, UninstallString, InstallLocation, InstallDate | out-gridview -PassThru



    write-host -ForegroundColor Yellow "The following software will be uninstalled:"




ForEach ($ver in $javaVer) {

    If ($ver.UninstallString) {

        $uninst = $ver.UninstallString
        & cmd /c $uninst /quiet /norestart
    }

}
} -credential $user
```

testing it in my local machine i got this error

> Out-GridView ne fonctionne pas à partir d’une session à distance.
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation : (Microsoft.Power...GridViewCommand:OutGridViewCommand) [Out-GridView] 
>   , NotSupportedException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemotingNotSupported,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutGridViewCommand
>       + PSComputerName        : 192.168.1.200

google translated:

> Out-GridView does not work from a remote session. + CategoryInfo:
>   InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Power ... GridViewCommand:
>   OutGridViewCommand) [Out-GridView], NotSupportedException +
>   FullyQualifiedErrorId: RemotingNotSupported,
>   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutGridViewCommand + PSComputerName:
>   192.168.1.200

but if i send a simple command like `ipconfig` ,it work

What i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: the `Out-GridView` cmdlet requires that one be in an interactive session. the session that `Invoke-Command` uses is both on the other system AND non-interactive. if you need user interaction, split your remote calls into two parts & use the returned info from the 1st in your local `Out-GridView` display.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey sorry i'm still learning powershell scripts, can you modify the code and post it as an answer please?

Comment: are you wanting to just uninstall a specific app - java, perhaps? that is implied by your `$JavaVer` variable name ...

Comment: @Lee_Dailey no, i want to choose from the opened list the software that i want to uninstall or input the name of the software but choosing from the list is easier for me

Comment: OK ... i think the code in the ANSWER i just posted will work, but i cannot  fully test is since i have only one system - and no apps that i want to uninstall. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Alright, no problem, i will test it and let you know

Comment: @Lee_Dailey did you posted an answer? i can't see it

Comment: i had a glitch and had to wait for my system to reboot & reconnect. the answer is there now.

Answer (score 1):

since you CANNOT run `Out-GridView` in a remote, non-interactive session [what you get from Invoke-Command], this breaks the process into steps ...

- asks for the target system name
- sets up two I-C scriptblocks
- gets the remote installed app list via I-C & the 1st scriptblock
- shows that via O-GV for the user to choose apps
- shows the to-be-uninstalled apps
- does the actual remote uninstall via a 2nd call to I-C using the 2nd scriptblock

note that the actual command to uninstall the apps has been converted to an expanded string. remove the double quotes around `"& cmd /c $uninst /quiet /norestart"` when ready to really do it.

also, there is NO error handling at all. [*grin*]

```
# the following likely should include a test to see if the system actually exists
$ComputerName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your server name or IP adress '
#$user = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your server username'
Write-Host ''

$ICScriptblock_One = {
    $HKLM_TargetList = @(
        "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*"
        "HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*"
        )
    # send the results to the calling system
    Get-ItemProperty -Path $HKLM_TargetList |
        Where-Object {
            # filter out items with blanks in the follwing properties
            $_.DisplayName -and
            $_.UninstallString
            } |
        Sort-Object -Property DisplayName |
        Select-Object -Property DisplayName, UninstallString, InstallLocation, InstallDate
    } # end >>> $ICScriptblock_One = {

$ICScriptblock_Two = {
    ForEach ($ATR_Item in $Using:AppsToRemove)
        {
        $uninst = $ATR_Item.UninstallString
        # remove the double quotes when ready to do this for real
        "& cmd /c $uninst /quiet /norestart"
        }
    } # end >>> $ICScriptblock_Two = {

$InstalledAppList = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock $ICScriptblock_One

$OGVMessage = 'Please select the software you wish to uninstall...'
$AppsToRemove = $InstalledAppList |
    Out-GridView -Title $OGVMessage -OutputMode Multiple

write-host -ForegroundColor Yellow "The following software will be uninstalled :"
$AppsToRemove.DisplayName |
    Out-Host
Write-Host ''

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock $ICScriptblock_Two
```

output on screen ...

```
Input your server name or IP adress : localhost

The following software will be uninstalled :
Apple Software Update
Google Update Helper
Python 3.7.4 Utility Scripts (64-bit)
Speccy

& cmd /c MsiExec.exe /I{A30EA700-5515-48F0-88B0-9E99DC356B88} /quiet /norestart
& cmd /c MsiExec.exe /I{60EC980A-BDA2-4CB6-A427-B07A5498B4CA} /quiet /norestart
& cmd /c MsiExec.exe /I{16F74529-EDE0-4BBD-B2AF-89AF9C696EA8} /quiet /norestart
& cmd /c "C:\Program Files\Speccy\uninst.exe" /quiet /norestart
```

Comment: i'm testing on VLC media player, but didn't uninstalled, also i'm not getting the same output, this part not shown `& cmd /c MsiExec.exe /I{A30EA700-5515-48F0-88B0-9E99DC356B88} /quiet /norestart
& cmd /c MsiExec.exe /I{60EC980A-BDA2-4CB6-A427-B07A5498B4CA} /quiet /norestart
& cmd /c MsiExec.exe /I{16F74529-EDE0-4BBD-B2AF-89AF9C696EA8} /quiet /norestart
& cmd /c "C:\Program Files\Speccy\uninst.exe" /quiet /norestart`

Comment: if you run the code as is ... no changes at all ... and give your local system as the `$ComputerName`, do the selected apps show up at all? the last two blocks of text should show the selected apps & the uninstall commands that _would_ be run.

Comment: yes, without changes at all, it gives the same output of yours

Comment: the code i posted in my question uninstall msi and non-msi installer, so VLC for example uninstalled successfully, can you look at your code and the code i posted maybe it need some changes in order to uninstall all the softwares,

Comment: `cmd /c "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\uninstall.exe" /quiet /norestart` when i write it in cmd it work, not silently, but it shows the window to do the uninstall process

Comment: @user11845248 - one thing is that i had to remove the credential stuff. have you added that back to each `Invoke-Command` call? also, i cannot test any deeper since i have no software that i am willing to uninstall - nor am i wiling to install something just to _uninstall_ it. [*blush*]

Comment: no, the only change i make in your code is removing double quotes that the comments said

Comment: i think the problem in cmd, it should run as administrator, but the code executed in normal cmd

Comment: @user11845248 - you may need to add `-Credential (Get-Credential)` to the 2nd `Invoke-Command` call - just after the `-Scriptblock` parameter stuff. again, this is not anything i can test, so we are using you as the tester. [*grin*]

Comment: @user11845248 - arg! yes, you need to start your powershell session `as administrator` to use that remotely.